# List of Objects as RequestParam in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to send a list of object id's (generated by the user selecting checkboxes) by **POST** to an action, so I can get a `java.util.List<MyObject>` converted using an `MyObjectEditor`.

So, is it possible to do this?

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder (WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(MyObject.class, new MyObjectEditor());
}
@RequestMapping (value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String action (@RequestParam List<MyObject> myList, Model model) {
    // more stuff here
}
```

And my POST would be like this:

```
myList[0] = 12
myList[1] = 15
myList[2] = 7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of binding is not supported by `@RequestParam`, so you have to use `@ModelAttribute`:

```
class MyObjects {
    private List<MyObject> myList;
    ...
}

public String action (@ModelAttribute MyObjects myObjects, Model model) { ... }
```

Comment: @axtavt: is there any other way to map a list? I see we can do that with a wrapping object, but sometimes it's just overkill.

Comment: Did anyone get around this ever?