# Spring @MVC how to obtain a List of JavaBeans from request params without wrapping the list inside an object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I need to have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/path/to/my/app")
public String process(List<JavaBean> javaBeans){
    // Do something with the list
}
```

At client I need to manually create the list on user actions, like so

```
<form action="/path/to/my/app">
    <input name="javaBeans[0].field1"/>
    <input name="javaBeans[0].field2"/>
    <input name="javaBeans[0].field3"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="javaBeans[1].field1"/>
    <input name="javaBeans[2].field2"/>
    <input name="javaBeans[3].field3"/>
    <!-- and so forth -->
</form>
```

My primary problem is that I receive empty list inside the contoller. I have to wrap it inside another javabean to make the code work. Like following

```
public class BeanWrapper{
    private List<JavaBean> javaBeans;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

and in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/path/to/my/app")
public String process(BeanWrapper wrapper){
    List<JavaBean> list = wrapper.getJavaBeans();
    // Do something with the list
}
```

This version works but I have to unnecessarily wrap my list around an object. Is there a way around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use spring:bind tag or spring form tag ?

Comment: I can very well do that, but the number of items in list can increase or decrease on client based on user action. I'd anyway need to figure out how to make it work in plain html. On another note, I am curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public String process(@RequestParam("javaBeans[]") List<JavaBean> javaBeans) {
```

**Update:**

The syntax using indices (`javaBeans[1]`) is currently not supported by the Spring default binding. As mentioned in the comments you can get around this limitation by using the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
public String process(@RequestBody List<JavaBean> javaBeans)
```

This requires a `POST` request, and either the data to be sent in a different format (e.g. JSON) or implementing your own message converter.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However I am getting this message `Required List parameter 'javaBeans[]' not present`

Comment: According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269042/list-of-objects-as-requestparam-in-spring-mvc) this kind of binding is not supported.

Comment: Too bad, it's beacuse of the indices. This has been discussed many times and afaik currently there is no other solution. You should be able to use `public String process(@RequestBody List<JavaBean> javaBeans) {` if you sent JSON to the server (via AJAX e.g.). Your solution may seem like unnecessary overhead but it's the easiest one. Maybe Spring 4 will provide a better solution.

Comment: As I call it, its a lamentable overkill.

Comment: can you please update the answer as no solution exists according to you comment so that I can accept that as an answer.